# XOR шифрование без использования ^

Tags: c#

Есть задание: написать XOR шифратор текста без использование упомянутого выше знака. В качестве подсказки сказали, что нужно переводить все в двоичный код. Как реализовать это?

Comment: Учебные задание делайте сами, плиз.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a ^ b` заменяется на  `(~a & b) | (a & ~b)`

шифрование строки через xor делается примерно так:

```
string original = "Hello, World!";
string encoded = new string(original.Select(c => (char)(c ^ 42)).ToArray());
string decoded = new string(encoded .Select(c => (char)(c ^ 42)).ToArray());
```

строка `encoded` скорее всего будет нечитабельной :)

Comment: А с текстом как быть? По заданию нужен xor шифратор текста не прибегая к знаку. Заранее извиняюсь за глупые вопросы :с

Comment: текст в любом случае шифруется посимвольно. один символ - один байт (считайте что это и есть перевод в двоичный код). код из ответа применим к байтам.

Comment: @Юрий держите полноценный пример